# Looping through array that's inside hash - perl

Tags: arrays, perl

Am I doing this right?

```
my $variable = "hello,world";

my @somearray = split(',',$variable);

my %hash = ( 'somevalue' => @somearray);

foreach my $key ( keys %hash ) {
    print $key;
    foreach my $value ( @{$hash{$key}} ) {
        print $value; #the value is not being read/printed
    }
}
```

I don't know if I'm accessing the array that is stored in the hash for the particular value

Comment: should i be using a for loop instead to access the arrays indexes?

Comment: Your hash does not contain what you think it does - @somearray gets expanded, so you are assigning (somevalue=>'hello', 'world') to the hash. Use \@somearray to store an array-ref instead. If you had "use warnings;" in your script, you would have been alerted to this: "Odd number of elements in hash assignment at test.pl line 10."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been bitten by perl's flattening nature of lists. You see, when you do:
`my %hash = ('somekey' => @somearray)`, perl converts that into a list form of hash assignment. So, what perl actually sees is:

```
my %hash = ('somekey' => 'hello', 'world' => ''); # I have put '' for simplicity, though it might well be `undef`
```

So, the next time you look up by 'somekey', you end up getting the string 'hello' and not the array "['hello', 'world']"

To fix this, you can use references. [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) can help you there for more information.

```
my %hash = ('somekey' => \@somearray);
# $hash{'somekey'} is an array reference now.
# So you use the pointy lookup syntax. 
print $hash{'somekey'}->[0];
```

Another useful tool in visualising data structures is using the module `Data::Dumper`. It's available in the perl core distribution. Using it is as simple as doing:

```
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper \%hash; # remember to pass in a reference to the actual datastructure, not the data structure itself.
```

Have fun!

Comment: this worked pretty cool, thx for telling me about Data Dumper :)

Comment: You're welcome. You can also turn on `strict` and `warnings` pragmas to aid you in your perl development. They act as your guardian angels to catch your mistakes. :-) To use them, put `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of every perl script you write.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
my %hash = ( 'somevalue' => @somearray);
```

The array is "flattened" to a list, so the line is equivalent to

```
my %hash = qw( somevalue hello world );
```

You need an array reference to create the inner array:

```
my %hash = ( 'somevalue' => \@somearray);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you wanted to create a hash of array data structure. Something like this will also work.

```
my $variable = "hello,world";

my @somearray = split(',',$variable);

my %hash;
#my %hash = ( 'somevalue' => @somearray);
push (@{$hash{'somevalue'}},@somearray);  #Storing it in a hash of array

foreach my $key ( keys %hash ) {
    print $key;
    foreach my $value ( @{$hash{$key}} ) {
        print $value; #the value is not being read/printed
    }
}
```

Comment: what was the reason for a down vote ? I suggested another way of doing it :)

Comment: i would upvote you but i don't know enough to say whether what you recommend is right or wrong :/

Comment: :) , I posted the code after testing. Anyway you can try it out and confirm the same. Please see this link http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch11_03.htm